# Flutter:Adding price sign with string in strings.arb creating expected an identifier in i18n file(localization)

Tags: localization, flutter

```
code:
Strings.arb
  "priceSign": "S$",
i18n.dart
  String priceSign(String ) => "S$";//Expected an identifier error
```

How  can i add localization for such a string in flutter.I can't able to create such a String in arb file and generate i18n.

ANyone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can define as below.

```
"price_sign" : "\$"
```

Its show red under line but you can ignore it and run application. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your ARB files you don't need to escape `$`, but in your dart getter code you should.

Strings.arb:

```
"priceSign": "S$",
```

i18n.dart:

```
String priceSign(String ) => "S\$";
```

If you use [intl_translation](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl_translation) tool, it will map it properly between those two formats.